# Can Sybase sp_help be used over different databases?

Tags: database, t-sql, sybase

Having changed SQL tools, one of the very useful things on the previous SQL editor was the ability to immediately enter a table and find out the 'structure' of it (columns, indices, keys and so on). The new tool does not have this ability but merely the ability to show you the full contents of a table, which can be a nightmare when the table is excessively large.
Sybase SQL does have the commands to find out all of the databases, which I have done using `db_name`, and the table table structure using `sp_help`. In order to make this work sensibly however, you must be in the correct database to run the `sp_help` command. My code is letting me down here as I need to run a `GO` midway through the routine. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can execute 'sp_help' in any db by prefixing the call with the database name, eg: `exec master..sp_helpdb`, `exec tempdb..sp_helpdb`, `exec <your_db_name_here>..sp_helpdb`; as for your other 'tool' issues ... the limited info you've provided sounds like you need to have a discussion with the tool developer (ie, this doesn't sounds like a Sybase issue); not enough info about the 'go' issue to comment at this time

Comment: Full credits to you - modifying the "sp_helpdb" works a treat. And unfortunately I agree, but I'm hoping that I just don't know this tool well enough...